# Timthumb error 500 on multiple requests - not on single load

Tags: 500-internal-error, timthumb

I'm getting a lot of error 500 related to timthumb.php on my site.

After some time debugging, I realized that, if I access the URL directly, it would work:

```
http://www.domain.com/wp-content/themes/sometheme/timthumb.php?src=http://www.domain.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/image.png&w=277&h=200&zc=1
```

However, if I keep refreshing it, and then let it load, it would throw error 500.

My images are intermitent, sometimes some of them load, some times not.

What could cause this kind of error? I don't see anything on the logs.

Comment: What error are you getting in your logs?

Comment: I don't see anything in the logs.

Comment: 1. how is this specific to wordpress? 2 When I hear timthumb I want to run as far away as possible.... that script just can not be made secure.